# Visual Studio local database to online database

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

I'm currently using a local database (`.sdf` - SQL Server CE) in my Visual Studio application and now I'm trying to use it as a online database but I have some doubts.

Code in use :

```
SqlCeConnection Conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" 
    + "|DataDirectory|\\Database1.sdf");
```

Does `SqlCeConnection` support online databases or only local?

If it does, what are the parameters I should use?

Answer (score 1):

**Sure**, it does support online databases, but for that you need to restore database in SQL Server. File system databases are not good for that. Install a SQL Server and restore your database there and a user with proper rights.

Now your connection string is like this

```
 Server=serverip\SQLServer;Database=database1;uid=abc;pwd=12345
```

Comment: First of all, this is switching from SQL Server **Compact** (`.sdf` file) to a "full-blown" SQL Server - there's no "backup-and-restore" path between those two.... and second: now with "full blown" SQL Server, you'll need to use `SqlConnection` (instead of `SqlCeConnection`)